How can I cover my basement floor & waterproof it?
I have about 420 SF of basement flooring I need to do something with. Backstory: We bought our home in 2019 and very shortly thereafter found out our basement gets water. Our house is a tri-level, so the basement is only half of the houses footprint. At first, we were only getting water on three sides (not including the slab side.
More recently it's been coming in everywhere. Not a crazy amount, but just enough to be annoying because it's not quite enough for surface pumps to take care of. Don't even get me started on how many have burnt out.
We decided to finally get a French drain installed, and in order to do that, had to have the existing asbestos tiles removed. Now, we are left with a very unsightly floor of old black mastic from around 1961.
My question is: what's the cheapest, easiest way to cover and waterproof the floor? I don't want to use any LVT. Is there a product anyone could recommend? Thanks in advance!

I suggest you should work to move the water away from your foundation instead of trying to waterproof the floor/walls, which you will always have trouble with.  The place a french drain goes is in your yard.

The existence of the French Drain means you have accepted that there will always be water in the basement.
Install a subfloor with a plastic underside to lift it off the floor and put your floor covering on top of that. Be prepared to use a dehumidifier in the space until you decide to move.
Alternatively, fix the drainage around the perimeter of the house so that water drains away from the foundation and if necessary, confirm that the drainage tiles around the exterior of the house foundation are working and that they are connected to the storm sewer system or a sump pit with an attached pump.
